# Problem with Twitter Cards: "Your Tweet was over 140 characters. You'll have to be more clever."

Tags: seo, html, meta-tags, twitter-card

Recently I've read about Twitter Cards and tried to use it on one page of my site.

Problem: When I put on Tweet tab I see the notification "Your Tweet was over 140 characters. You'll have to be more clever." What is the problem?

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@EliteWritings">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Capstone Project Help">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="If you need valuable Capstone project help, you should get in touch with our trustworthy company | Our skilled experts will produce exclusive papers for you">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://elitewritings.com/media/articles/42-vU7WLv04uS.jpg">
```

Answer (score 3):

Twitter has it's [140 character limit](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters). That's why you're getting this error.  It looks like your description is not automatically truncated to 140 characters.

I would suggest using Open Graph Tags, which are automatically picked up by Facebook, Twitter and Google Plus.

Like this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/your-page-url/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Page Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Your Long Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/my-pic.jpg" />
```

Comment: How about this https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Comment: Elit@Thanks for your support :) It was my mistake :)

Comment: I asked why it doesn't work on the page